# What are the earliest dated Syriac manuscripts of the Bible?

Tags: manuscript, syriac

What is the dating of the earliest Syriac manuscript of the Hebrew Tanakh (Old Testament)?
What is the dating of the earliest Syriac manuscript of the New Testament?
Who is in current possession of these manuscripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary**

The oldest extant New Testament text appears to be the Syriac Sinaitic a collection of gospels in the Old Syriac textual tradition dated to the 4th century.  The oldest extant Old Testament text dates to the 5th century.  These are about as old as the earliest Greek texts, and much older than all extant Hebrew texts except for the Dead Sea Scrolls.

**New Testament**

There are several different Syriac New Testament textual traditions:  the Old Syriac (gospels only), the Peshitta (the whole New Testament except 2 Peter, 2&3 John, and Revelation), and the Diatessaron (a gospel harmony).

**The Old Syriac:**
The oldest extant manuscripts of the Old Syriac gospels are the [Syriac Sinaitic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syriac_Sinaiticus) and the [Curetonian Gospels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curetonian_Gospels).  The Syriac Sinaitic is a palimpsest (that is a text where the original was scraped off and another text written on top) found at St. Catherine's Monastery on the Sinai peninsula (the same location as the more famous Codex Sinaiticus).  It has been dated paleographically to the mid to late 4th century.  The Curetonian gospels have been dated paleographically to the early 5th century.  This tradition is widely believed to date back to the late 2nd century, and appears in the quotations in the writings of [St. Ephrem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephrem_the_Syrian) an Eastern church father in the from the 4th century.  The writings of St. Ephrem suggest that there were Old Syriac versions of Acts and the letters of Paul, but there are no extant original texts.

**Peshitta**
The textual tradition with the greatest number of manuscripts is the [Peshitta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshitta), which was the standard text of the Eastern church since at least the early 5th century.  The [oldest extant text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Library,_Add._14479) is dated by colophon (that is the scribe wrote the date) to 534 AD.  There are several other 6th century texts, some of which may be slightly earlier (e.g. [this manuscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Library,_Add._14459)).

**Diatessaron**
Sometime between 160 and 175 AD, Tatian made a gospel harmony called the [Diatessaron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatessaron).  Although this is not considered canonical now (and was declared heretical in the 5th century) it was the standard version of the gospels used in many eastern churches in the 3rd and 4th centuries.  It is unknown whether it was translated from a Greek harmony or written directly in Syriac.  Although we have many ancient references to the Diatessaron and quotations of its contents, there are no complete extant texts.

**Old Testament**

The Peshitta Old Testament was translated directly from Hebrew with some influence from Aramaic commentaries called Targums.  This translation is believed to have taken place in roughly the first century AD.  The oldest extant manuscript dates to the late 5th century (London, British Library, Add. 14,425).

Many more texts can be found listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshitta) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_Syriac_New_Testament_manuscripts).

Comment: Peshitta is considered as Original New Testament by Several Eastern Churches. But many earliest manuscripts were destroyed. That's why there are some south indians who don't like European christians. Many infos about Peshitta are available at Peshitta.org

Answer (score 3):

Earliest "surviving" Aramaic manuscript (a.k.a Syriac) dates to 5th century AD (Syriac manuscript # 14,470) which is available at British Library. Many of the earliest Aramaic manuscripts were destroyed.

For Example, Archbishop Menezies succeeded in destroying ancient Aramaic manuscipts (includes OT and NT) which was preserved in Kerala (South India) until early 1600s. Because of this, there are south indian christians who dislike European Christians.

The Khabouris Manuscript (11th century Aramaic Peshitta NT manuscript) is a copy of a Second Century New Testament, which was written in approximately 165 AD. Aramaic and Hebrew scribes usually annotate their copy with a notation that identifies the source document they copied. The annotation is called a "colophon". The colophon in the Khabouris Codex identifies its SOURCE as a document that existed about 165 CE.

When Khabouris Manuscript was found, the news article "US Library gets an Ancient Bible" appeared in the New York Times on March 26, 1955 reporting on the oldest known New Testament Bible written in the language "used by Christ". The article noted how it was taken to the White House where President Eisenhower viewed it. The Bible was said to be insured for "an hour and a half" in the amount of $1,500,000 US dollars. 
When the Khabouris Codex was first revealed to America in April 1955 it was referred to as "the NT Time Bomb."

Here is a website that explains about Aramaic Peshitta Tanakh (Aramaic OT) from first century AD.

http://pshitta.org/english/index.php#contents

Information about Aramaic Eastern Peshitta (Aramaic NT) are available at the below website. You may contact Aramaic scholars at the below website for more information on Aramaic Peshitta NT.

www.peshitta.org

Comment: Could you give some references for your claim that the source for the Khabouris Codex was from 165 CE?  This appears to be a fringe position with little scholarly support.

Comment: Let me give you a website - http://www.aent.org/ntbomb.htm I think you are talking about Western Scholarly support. Not Eastern scholarly support. Eastern Scholars believe that Aramaic is the language of New Testament. But Western Scholars believe Greek is the language of New Testament. So be specific when you say scholarly support.

Comment: That link says next to nothing about how it was dated to 165. It appears to be a publicity page trying to sell a book.  I'd be interested in seeing any peer reviewed scholarly articles or books, whether Western or Eastern.

Comment: As for information about Aramaic primacy and Eastern viewpoint about Aramaic primacy, I highly recommend you to visit peshitta.org forum. There are lots of documents and information at this website. You may also ask Aramaic scholars for information. If I write information here, then it will be far too long and too much time. On the top of that, no one will read it either.

Comment: You have to understand that Khabouris Manuscript is considered valuable among Eastern Christians including myself. Noah reads the website and reaches to his own conclusion and calls it a publicity page trying to sell a book instead of understanding the value of Khabouris Manuscript that is mentioned in this website. If he talks like that, then my reply will be harsh. He needs to show some respect through his writings. He may not value Khabouris Manuscript at all. But to me, Khabouris Manuscript is a treasure.

Comment: (continuation) I would have helped if he said "I couldn't find the information. Can you help me?" Instead, he reaches to his own conclusion by saying "That link says next to nothing about how it was dated to 165." So I don't like to provide the information to a person who has this kind of attitude.

Comment: Certainly any manuscript that has survived for a thousand years is a treasure and of great value.  I did not mean to insult the manuscript or your religious tradition.

Comment: That is nice to hear. You also have to understand that this manuscript was given great deal of respect during the presidency of Dwight Eisenhower. So it was also respectfully welcomed by Western Christianity in 1950s.

Comment: It appears to me that the 165 date has been abandoned even among Aramaic primacists in favor of a mid 4th century date during the persecution of Shapur II in Persia.  See http://www.peshitta.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=889&p=5113&hilit=khabouris#p5113 and http://www.peshitta.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=198#p618

Comment: Some Aramaic primacists do believe that Shapur II period could have been a possible date. That is certainly a possibility. I am not denying it. But "generally" accepted time period is 165 AD, because it was verified under Archdeacon and Pastor Sadook De Mar Eshai Shimun and also Fr. Michael Ryce. So I used "generally" accepted time period of Khabouris.  Either way, we all can agree on one thing - Khabouris was a copy of an older Aramaic manuscript. If I get a "confirmation" that 165 date is not the date for Khabouris colophon, then I can change it.

Comment: The article in New York Times mentioned in konwayk's answer does not talk about Khabouris but about Yonan codex! See http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9502E3D61E3FE33BBC4E51DFB566838E649EDE&mcubz=1 Khabouris codex wasn't discovered yet at that time. See https://fortheloveoftruth.wordpress.com/2010/08/25/myth-khaboris-codex/